# Structure Alignment and padding in c++

Tags: c++

How output is changing for the codes?
i know

```
struct-declarator:

declarator

type-specifier declarator opt : constant-expression
```

here constant-expression specifies the width of the field in bits.

```
#include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        struct value{
           int bit1 : 8;
           int bit3 : 8;
           int bit4 : 8;
           }bit;


       printf("%d\n",sizeof(bit));
     return 0;
}
```

output is 4

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct value{
       int bit1 : 1;
       int bit3 : 4;
       int bit4 : 4;
       }bit;


       printf("%d\n",sizeof(bit));
     return 0;
}
```

output 4

```
#include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        struct value{
           int bit1 : 1;
           int bit3 : 16;
           int bit4 : 16;
           }bit;


           printf("%d\n",sizeof(bit));
         return 0;
    }
```

output is 8

As far as i know size of struct is the size of all data types declare inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: it depends. The standard imposes no requirements on the layout of bit fields. Specifically,

> Allocation of bit-fields within a class
>   object is implementation-defined. Alignment of bit-fields is implementation-defined. Bit-fields are packed
>   into some addressable allocation unit. [ Note: Bit-fields straddle allocation units on some machines and not
>   on others. Bit-fields are assigned right-to-left on some machines, left-to-right on others. —end note ]

- Assuming 32-bit integers the maximum space requirement for each is `3*sizeof(int)`, or 12, 12, 12 bytes.
- With maximal packing the minimum sizes are respectively 3, 3, 4 bytes, depending perhaps on `#pragma pack`.
- A typical result might well be 4, 4, 8 but that could easily vary from one compiler to another.

So the answer is: it all depends. This is one reason I strongly advise against the use of bit fields anytime the layout or size requirements are important. Shift and mask is much more predictable.

Answer (score 4):

This is because of the Packing and byte alignment. Check [structure alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)

Check [C-FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/struct/align.html) for details

It's for ``alignment''. Many processors can't access 2- and 4-byte quantities (e.g. ints and long ints) if they're crammed in every-which-way.

Suppose you have this structure:

```
struct  {
    char a[3];
    short int b;
    long int c;
    char d[3];
    };
```

Now, you might think that it ought to be possible to pack this structure into memory like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|           a           |   b   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   b   |           c           |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   c   |           d           |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

But it's much, much easier on the processor if the compiler arranges it like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|           a           |
+-------+-------+-------+
|       b       |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|               c               |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|           d           |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

In the `packed'' version, notice how it's at least a little bit hard for you and me to see how the b and c fields wrap around? In a nutshell, it's hard for the processor, too. Therefore, most compilers will`pad'' the structure (as if with extra, invisible fields) like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|           a           | pad1  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       b       |     pad2      |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|               c               |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|           d           | pad3  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Also check this **[C-Faq](http://c-faq.com/struct/align.esr.html)**

Comment: so why is the output of first code 4 and not 6??
and ouput of second code must be 3 and output of 3rd code must be 6

Comment: I think you mis interpreted it, it is because, along with structure members, structure type variables will also have natural alignment.

Comment: ohkk so structure type variables will take the same space as structure member although structure variable is supposed to contain all the structure members?

Comment: @user3762730:- I have added the link which will surely help you! :)

Comment: i am not getting this "structure type variables will also have natural alignment" and due to this answer of second code must be 2